# How to make placeholder for 'select' box which fetch's data from mySQL?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to add placeholder for my drop-box which gets results from mySQL and I don't know is there a way or not.

```
<div class="select_drp">
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM training_list"); 
        echo '<select class="select_drp" name="insert_training" required>'; 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['training_type'].'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo "<br/><br/>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: did u means placeholder attribute? or selected option? mysql_* is depreacted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this, I've added `<option value="">Placeholder</option>`, I think you
can use this as a placeholder.

```
<div class="select_drp">
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM training_list");
    echo '<select class="select_drp" name="insert_training" required>';
    echo '<option value="">Placeholder</option>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['training_type'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<div class="select_drp">
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM training_list"); 
        echo '<select class="select_drp" name="insert_training" required>'; 
        echo '<option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Please Choose</option>'; //This line your placeholder
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
           echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['training_type'].'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo "<br/><br/>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Added <option> tag should be inside the <select> element

Comment: why `display: none;` ?

Comment: if you use `display:none` when you open select box placeholder does not show option list.

Answer (score 2):

If you talk for option inside the results from MySQL you can disable it like that

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" disabled>'.$row['training_type'].'</option>';
```

If you talk for placeholder in select dropdown along with results from MySQL before your loop simply put another

```
<select>
    <option value="">placeholder</option>
    <?php
       ...
       while ( ... ) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['training_type'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select>
```